# Passing a variable class object through to a class

Tags: c#

I'm trying to work out if the following is possible, I've done lots of googling and I'm a bit confused. I'm pretty sure I can work out the class reflection on the object class and updating the database isn't a problem once I have the loop, but I can't work out if this is possible at all.

If I was doing this with a fixed class object it'd be easy I'd just do:

```
public void updateDB(obj_Users myObject)
```

But as I have a lot of class objects that will take a long time, so trying to make it more dynamic.

Here is a sample of a class I want to pass through (but could be anything following the same format):

```
public class obj_Users
{
    public Int32 UserID { get; set; }
    public String UserName { get; set; }
    public String FirstName { get; set; }
    public String Surname { get; set; }
    public String Email { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserRole { get; set; }
    public Int32 UserCompanyID { get; set; }
    public String UserPassword { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsAdmin { get; set; }
    public String SessionKey { get; set; }
}
```

Here is some pseudocode of what I'm trying to achieve to explain:

```
public void updateDB(AnyClassObject obj_Users)
{
    // Loop through obj_Users and grab the properties

    // DB update call
}
```

Comment: You can get the properties using `obj_Users.GetType().GetProperties()`, is there anything in particular you are stuck with?

Comment: Sorry getiting the properties isnt the issue, its the being able to pass the object through to updateDB i can't work out

Comment: Is AnyClassObject an ancestor of obj_Users?

Comment: Just make the parameter of type `object`, then you can pass in an instance of any class or struct.

Comment: Sorry, my bad explaining. AnyClassObject doesnt exist, its psudocode for what i'm trying to achieve. I can't work out what that should be

Comment: @Tom you want to make `updateDB` as generic method? which take any object?

Comment: Yeh, basically thats it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
public void updateDB(object paramobj)
{
    foreach(var prop in paramobj.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
           //grab
    }
    // update
 }
```

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve though is to not have to list each object in the if - i have like 100 objects so that's the bit i'm trying to make dynamic

Comment: That makes sense. How do I call that though? When i do  DBCommon dbc = new DBCommon(); dbc.updateDB(obj_Users); it tells me that obj_Users is a type but used like a variable

Comment: Of course it tells you that. obj_Users is a class, you need to create an instance of it and pass it to your method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to loop to get the properties

```
foreach(var prop in obj_Users.GetType().GetProperties()) {
    //use your props
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need your parameter to be of type `object` to pass an instance of any class or struct.

```
public void updateDB(object whatever)
{
    foreach(var prop in whatever.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
       ... //do stuff
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with the problem of having to deal with different classes, a generic method should fit your needs:

```
public void UpdateDB<T>(T obj)
{
    var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties();

    foreach (var prop in properties)
    {
        // Here you loop through the properties.
    }
}
```